# Удалить натуральное число из заданного числа

Tags: javascript

Из натурального числа удалить заданную цифру. Число вводится с клавиатуры. Например задано число 568325. требуется убрать из него 8. Получится число 56325.

Comment: А если таких цифр несколько?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let number = 568325;

number = +number.toString().split("").filter(i=>+i!=8).join("");
  
console.log(number);
```

или такой вариант без строк и массивов.

```js
let number = 5683825;

function removeNumber(number, excludeDig){
   number = number|0;
   if (number > 0) {
      let res = number / 10;  
      let frac = number % 10;
      return (frac == excludeDig)? removeNumber(number/10, excludeDig): frac + 10 * removeNumber(number/10, excludeDig);
   } else { 
      return 0;
   }
}
number = removeNumber(number, 8)
  
console.log(number);
```

Comment: А зачем такие сложности с `filter` в 1 варианте? Почему не просто `.split('8').join('')`?

Comment: @Yaant просто если не видеть сложности то откуда понять что есть проще? Чтобы понять пользу плуга нужно лопатой покопать

Answer (score 1):

```
const value = 5683825;

const result = Number(String(value).replace('8', ''));
// const result = +(value + '').replace('8', '')

console.log(result);
```